# Want to reduce database hits

Tags: sql-server, database, performance

I have real time attendance application. I am using Angular as front end and SQL Server as backend.

I want to take attendance of more than 1000 people, so I thought to add their unique identification numbers in array and finally save the same. But, I am worried about what if internet connection get lost in between, then will lose all the data. So, as a work around thought to take one attendance at a time (may take 5 seconds) and save it which will increase API calls and database hits, which may raise error or performance issue.

So, will this be create issue? What work around is available to solve the same?

Comment: If its critical you know an update has occurred then you need to implement a method of retying in the event of failure. The retry mechanism would work the same regardless of whether its 1 record or 1000 and will need a way of knowing, at the database level, whether the update took place or not. Thats a complex design, not something that can be answered in a single question.

Comment: You should learn how to implement something like WebSockets for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

The network and the app will react faster than the time you take to go to the next person and click so why are you worried? 1000 people is nothing for a DB

Comment: So do you there is no harm if there is one db hit per 5 secs?

Comment: Depends on your system configuration, but most databases can handle 1000's of hits per second.

Comment: Unless the query takes more than 5 seconds then you wouldn’t be adding any load to the system.